# JPA delete an entry from list in Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Those are my classes. I want to delete items from **likedCourses**. So I expect JPA to delete item from **course_like** table. I looked and try to understand from other examples but couldn't. It is like deletion doesn't exist in JPA realm when there is relation. It is good for selecting though. I'd want to share what I tried but I couldn't find anything about it.

Note : I see that in ManyToMany relationship there is not orphanRemoval option.

```
@Entity
class Student {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
    name = "course_like", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
    Set<Course> likedCourses
}


@Entity
class Course {

    @Id
    Long id;

   
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likedCourses")
    Set<Student> likes;
}
```

Comment: This code won't even compile, you have specified the 'likes' member variable in class Course twice

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an entry from the `course_like` table, you will have to load the `Student` and remove the element from the `likedCourses` set that should be removed. If you do that in a `@Transactional` method, you will see that Hibernate will emit `delete` statements to delete the rows that represent the removed objects from the `likedCourses` set. That's the magic of an ORM, it synchronizes the object graph with the database, without you telling it to emit statement A, B, ...